# Conversion of special characters in PHP

Tags: php, string, character-encoding

I've tried many functions already, but I simply can't figure this out. The right way, anyway.

In a form field called description, I can expect all kinds of characters. These need to be formatted into HTML entities before they're submitted to the db.

Now, my code:

```
$formdesc = htmlentities($_POST['formdesc'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

For a MySQL query, I simply add a "safe" function to slash the ' off the string:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($formdesc);
```

However, this sometimes doesn't work. "é," for instance, becomes Ã© instead of é.

There must be a normal function for this. Does anyone know what I mean?

Comment: Wouldn't this have to do with the language setting for your database?

Comment: Yeah it seems like a unicode issue. In general, try to use utf8 for both your database and your frontend.

Comment: yes, i forgot the utf-8 encoding setting in encoding my string :) thx!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to specify the encoding for the [`htmlentities` function](http://docs.php.net/htmlentities) (here UTF-8):

```
$formdesc = htmlentities($_POST['formdesc'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Otherwise the default value `ISO-8859-1` is used and the character `é` in your example encoded in UTF-8 as 0xC3A9 would be interpreted as two characters (`Ã` and `©`).

But why do you use `htmlentities` anyway? If you just want to escape the HTML special characters like `&`, `<`, `>`, `"` and `'` [`htmlspecialchars`](http://docs.php.net/htmlspecialchars) will suffice.

Comment: it works!! duh, so simple... but thx! btw > why > it seemed safer that way, am i wrong?

Comment: You just need to replace additional character with character references if that characters cannot be encoded with the encoding you use. But as Unicode contains any known character and UTF-8 can encode it, you don’t need to replace any other characters than HTML’s special characters.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried looking at [htmlspecialchars()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and [htmlspecialchars_decode()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Josh

Comment: thx, yes i've tried but i want to have the &eacute; translation. htmlspecialchars() only does &, ", <, >, etc right?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the usual PHP escaping functions do not work on utf-8 text. Maybe [Handling UTF-8 in JavaScript, PHP, and Non-UTF8 Databases](http://www.dangrossman.info/2007/05/25/handling-utf-8-in-javascript-php-and-non-utf8-databases/) will help you. Another source about utf-8 and PHP is the [PHP UTF-8 cheatsheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet).

Comment: thx for your comment but i've got it working now. i forgot the utf-8 tag yes, thx!

Comment: You are welcome. I see Gumbo's answer was exactly the right thing to make this work.