# String Conversion to proper format

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, special-characters

I have this string fetched from Database:

```
$string = "Meubles salle Ã";
```

Some characters are not fetched in right order as they suppose to be.

How can I convert them into its original format?

**Things I tried:**

```
echo utf8_decode($string);

echo utf8_encode($string);

echo htmlentities($string);

echo htmlentities($string,0,"UTF-8");
```

Nothing works. Can anyone provide me a solid and perfect solution for this ? Thanks

Comment: do you want to replace Ã with A?

Comment: I have to many characters of that type this is just an example

Comment: Then you will get answer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127744/how-to-convert-these-strange-characters

Comment: In Stackoverflow itself, you have a lot of answers for your question.

below link also :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062181/conversion-of-special-characters-in-php

Comment: None of the above are working. Plus already tried them

Comment: try this : hope you will get answer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354195/issues-replacing-special-characters-in-php-string